# CPU (all cores) become idle during python multiprocessing on windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pandas, multiprocessing

My system is windows 7. I wrote python program to do data analysis. I use `multiprocessing` library to achieve parallelism. When I open windows powershell, and type `python MyScript.py`. It starts to use all the cpu cores. But after a while, the CPU (all cores) became idle. But if I hit `Enter` in powershell window, all cores are back to full-load. To be clear, the program is fine, and has been tested. The problem here is that CPU-cores went idle by themselves.

This happened not only on my office computer, which runs Windows 7 Pro, but also on my home desktop, which runs Windows 7 Ultimate.

The parallel part of the program is very simple:

```
def myfunc(input):
    ##some operations based on a huge data and a small data##

    operation1: read in a piece of HugeData #query based HDF5
    operation2: some operation based on HugeData and SmallData

    return output

# read in Small data
SmallData=pd.read_csv('data.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    result=pool.map_async(myfunc, a_list_of_input)
    out=result.get()
```

My function are mainly data manipulations using `Pandas`.

There is nothing wrong with the program, because I've successfully finished my program couple times. But I have to keep watching it, and hit `Enter` when cores become idle. The job takes couple hours, and I really don't keep watching it.

Is this a problem of windows system itself or my program?

By the way, can all the cores have access to the same variable stored in the memory? e.g. I have a data set `mydata` read into memory right before `if __name__ == '__main__':`. This data will be used in `myfunc`. All the cores should be able to access `mydata` in the same time, right?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confess to not understanding the subtleties of map_async, but I'm not sure whether you can use it like that (I can't seem to get it to work at all)...

I usually use the following recipe (a list comprehension of the calls I want doing):

```
In [11]: procs = [multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=()) for _ in xrange(4)]
   ....: for p in procs: p.start()
   ....: for p in procs: p.join()
   ....:
```

*It's simple and waits until the jobs are finished before continuing.*

This works fine with pandas objects provided you're not doing modifications... (I think) copies of the object are passed to each thread and if you perform mutations they not propogate and will be garbage collected.

You can use multiprocessing's version of a dict or list with the Manager class, this is useful for storing the result of each job (simply access the dict/list from within the function):

```
mgr = multiproccessing.Manager()
d = mgr.dict()
L = mgr.list()
```

and they will have shared access (as if you had written a Lock). It's hardly worth mentioning, that if you are appending to a list then the order will not just be the same as procs!

*You **may** be able to do something similar to the Manager for pandas objects (writing a lock to objects in memory without copying), but I think this would be a non-trivial task...*

Comment: It's no different from `pool.map()`, I have the program actually running now, so... 

I was wondering if the CPU tempreature is getting too high, and it's a protective mechanism. The parallel in my program is essentially cutting huge data into small pieces and have independent operations for each piece. Finally join them. And BTW, `multiprocessing` doesn't work in python.

Comment: I edited the original question, so now you can see my work flow.

Comment: @user3576212 what do you mean it doesn't work in python? My f here was a function that calculates df.sum() 10000 times (so takes a couple of seconds)... it basically takes the same amount of time doing it 4 times as one time.

Comment: your answer didn't actually answer my question. But I appreciate the effort! So I will still vote it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was re-directed to this question as I was facing a similar problem while using Python's Multiprocessing library in Ubuntu. In my case, the processes do not start by hitting enter or such, however, they start after sometime abruptly. My code is an iterative heuristic that uses multiprocessing in each of its iterations. I have to rerun the code after completion of some iterations in order to get a steady runtime-performance. As the question was posted way long back, did you come across the actual reason behind it and solution to it?